# async programming, async's in asycns

Tags: f#

I have a DU (don't worry about the specific types, but 2 normal options, or some errors)

```
type Content = 
    | Episode of EpisodeJSON.Root
    | Program of string
    | Errors of List<exn>
```

I have 2 functions (again the specifics don't matter, just the types):

```
let getEpisode : _ -> _ -> Async<Content> = ...

let getProgram : _ -> _ -> Async<Content> = ...
```

I want to write

```
let getContent : _ -> _ -> Async<Content> = 
   fun (contentBAPIClient: ContentBAPI.Client) id -> ...
```

such that, it tries to get the data from getEpisode, if there's an error, it tries to get it from getProgram, and if there is an error again, it returns both errors as the Error DU.

so, this works

```
let getContent : _ -> _ -> Async<Content> = 
    fun (contentBAPIClient: ContentBAPI.Client) id -> 
        async {
            let! episodeMaybe = getEpisode contentBAPIClient id
            let! programMaybe = getProgram contentBAPIClient id

            return
                match episodeMaybe with
                | Errors xs -> 
                    match programMaybe with
                    | Errors ys -> 
                        Errors (List.append xs ys)
                    | program ->
                        program
                | episode -> 
                    episode
        }
```

but I notice that getprogram is being executed even when the data is found via getepisode.

How do i structure this simple function to try getEpisode first, then only try getProgram if episode 'fails'

---

this works, still feels a bit clunky

```
let getContent : _ -> _ -> Async<Content> = 
    fun (contentBAPIClient: ContentBAPI.Client) id -> 
        async {
            let! episodeMaybe = getEpisode contentBAPIClient id

            match episodeMaybe with
            | Errors xs -> 
                let! programMaybe = getProgram contentBAPIClient id
                match programMaybe with
                | Errors ys -> 
                    return Errors (List.append xs ys)
                | program ->
                    return program
            | episode -> 
                return episode
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get a lot easier if you use some library that lets you work with values representing asynchronous computations that may fail, i.e. type `Async<Result<'TOk, 'TErrror>>`.

A good choice would be something like [FsToolkit.ErrorHandling](https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling). This defines the `asyncResult` computation expression as well as a number of primitives that you may find useful.

To get this to compile, I started with this:

```
#r "nuget: FsToolkit.ErrorHandling"
open FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

type Client = class end 

let getEpisode contentBAPIClient id = 
  async { return Error ["no episode"] }

let getProgram contentBAPIClient id = 
  async { return Ok "fine" }
```

Now, to do what (I think) you are doing, you can use:

```
let getContent (contentBAPIClient: Client) id = 
  getEpisode contentBAPIClient id
  |> AsyncResult.orElseWith (fun e1 ->
      getProgram contentBAPIClient id
      |> AsyncResult.mapError (fun e2 -> e1 @ e2) )
```

Here, we try to return the episode, but if there is not one, we try to get program (using `orElseWith`). The only tricky thing is that we need to pass the errors from the first call, which are then appended to (potential) errors of the second call using `mapError`.

Note that you can also write:

```
let getContent (contentBAPIClient: Client) id = 
  asyncResult {
    let! ep = getEpisode contentBAPIClient id
    and! prog = getProgram contentBAPIClient id
    return ep, prog }
```

This succeeds only if both calls succeed, so it can be quite useful in many scenarios, but does not exactly do the thing that you are trying to do.